# Importing Word Tables to Excel Based on Content

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having trouble grabbing only the tables I need into Excel. The Word Documents I'm working with consist of various tables but only the ones with certain key words need to be put into excel.

The code loops through the folder creating a worksheet for each file, but when it comes to searching the table for the key phrase, I receive an error in line 28.

I'm new to this, so any suggestions would be appreciated

```
Sub FormatWordTables()

Dim WB As Workbook
Set WB = ThisWorkbook
Dim BOM As Worksheet
Set BOM = WB.Sheets("BoM")
lastBOM = BOM.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim file As String
file = Dir("C:\folder\*.docx")

' create worksheet with the name of the file
Do While file <> ""
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = file
Dim wdDoc As Object
Set wdDoc = GetObject("C:\folder\" & file)

Dim TableNo As Long 'table number in Word
Dim iRow As Long 'row index in Excel
Dim iCol As Long 'column index in Excel
Dim tblCount As Long
With wdDoc
    TableNo = wdDoc.tables.Count
    For tblCount = 1 To wdDoc.tables.Count
        ' search through tables in Doc for specific text
        With .tables(tblCount)
        Dim STable As Object
        Set STable = .Range(Start:=wdDoc.tables(tblCount).Cell(1, 1).Range.Start, _
        End:=wdDoc.tables(tblCount).Cell(2, .Columns.Count).Range.End)
        SText = "Identifying Text"
        Dim Match As Range
        Set Match = Nothing
        Set Match = STable.Find(What:=SText)

        ' if text is found copy data to excel sheet
        If Match <> 0 Then

            For iRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
               'find the last empty row in the current worksheet
                nextRow = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("a" _
                    & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                For iCol = 1 To .Columns.Count
                .Cell(iRow, iCol).Range.Copy
                ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(nextRow, iCol).Activate
                ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Paste
                Next iCol
            Next iRow
        End If
        End With
    Next tblCount
End With
Set wdDoc = Nothing

file = Dir()
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you upload an example Word document that this should work on?

Comment: Did you google vba Error 91? Do you know which line it happens on?

Comment: Yes, I got error 91 on line 16

Answer (score 0):

Line 16 is missing the folder separator and should be:

```
Set wdDoc = GetObject("C:\folder\" & file)
```

Edit:
So you are only looking for text in the first two rows of the table. Changing your code as below should work for you.

```
With .tables(tblCount)
Dim STable As Range
Set STable = .Range
STable.MoveEnd wdRow, -(.Rows.Count - 2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Debugging gets past that part. I am having an error in line 28, where I'm establishing the Word table as a searchable range.